# How to provide selection button on JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I wants user to give me ability to choosing options from my JOptionPane so that I can execute different functionality based on his input.
this is my piece of code:

```
public GUI() {

        super("lol");
        setContentPane(heroPanel);
        pack();

        chenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(GUI.this, "Are u sure?");

            }
```

so i can click yes, no or cancel buttons...
when i click yes must apear message dialog with some text "1";
if no, other text dialog "2";
 and one more question: can i delete or hide "cancel" button?

Comment: WTF??? How can a JButton be converted to an int? Please edit your question title OR else it's gonna get closed...

Comment: i know that we can convert jbutton to int, ok...my fault i change it now

Comment: Take a look at the Java docs for questions like these in the future.

Comment: @lpq66-That's not conversion of JButton to int but a return of variable which is of pre-defined type---int here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

`int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure?", "Title", YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);`

`value` will now either be YES_OPTION, NO_OPTION, or CANCEL_OPTION, depending on what they clicked.